# How to interpret MP_REACH_NLRI attribute with address length of 32 bytes contained in a MRT Dump

Tags: bgp, protocol-theory, rfc, bgp-ipv6

While parsing an [TABLE_DUMP_V2 RIB_IPV6_UNICAST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6396#page-9) entry I encountered this binary sequence representing a [MP_REACH_NLRI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4760) BGP Path Attribute:

```
80 E 26 0 2 1 20 20 1 5 4 0 1 0 0 0 0 A5 1 30 30
 0 1 FE 80 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1B ED FF FE 32 A1 1 0 0
```

Whereas:

```
  Attribute Header
  80  -> 10000000 attribute is optional and no other flag set
  E   -> attribute type 14 (MP_REACH_NLRI)
  26  -> a length of 38 octets
  Attribute
  0 2 -> AFI-Type two is IPv6 (as indicated by dump subtype)
  1   -> SAFI-Type 1 which is unicast (as indicated by dump subtype)
  20  -> indicates a length of 32 bytes
```

And that last part is the point where I am confused as an IPv6 address is supposed to be at most 16 bytes of length and the rfc does not state that more than a single next hop address can be specified.

**How am I supposed to interprete an IPv6 address(es?) of length 32 in this context?**

Comment: Is it multiple prefixes?  I need to read about MRT to provide a more useful input...

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, I provided the links of the corresponding RFCs in the question. If you clear up your question I am happy to provide further details if I am able to.

Comment: I skimmed the relevant section but didn't have the time to piece it all together. Maybe someone with MRT experience will come along and be able to provide a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32 length specifies 16 bytes of global ipv6 address and 16 bytes for link-local address. See "RFC- 2545 Use of BGP-4 Multiprotocol Extensions for IPv6 Inter-Domain Routing" for more details.